# Why do Exception classes that extend the base Java Exception class not get caught?

Tags: java, exception, extends

Given the following program:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int x = 0;
        try {
            throw new Exception2();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {x += 1;}
        catch (Exception1 e) {x += 2;}
        catch (Exception2 e) {x += 3;}
    }
}


class Exception1 extends Exception {

}

class Exception2 extends Exception1 {

}
```

Both catch lines with Exception1 and Exception2 are giving an error that they are unreachable. Why exactly is this? I am throwing a new Exception2 and so I would expect the Exception2 catch block to run.

Comment: The first block that matches gets executed. Since `Exception2` (indireclty) `extends Exception` the `catch (Exception e) {x += 1;}` gets execute. All other blocks are then skipped.

Comment: in return, this means that  in the code presented, `catch (Exception1 e) {...}` and `catch (Exception2 e) {...}` are effectively dead code.

Comment: So when the the catch statement executes, what is it actually checking for in the Exception object type? A specific variable type or method that Exception1 and 2 inherit from Exception, or something else?

Comment: I do not fully understand your question. The runtime type of the exception is evaluated. If the runtime type is assignable to the exception-type mentioned in the `catch`-clause, the `catch`-block is exeucted.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is simply the order in which you are catching the exception. Start from the most specific Exception classes and end with the most broad (ie Exception)

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int x = 0;
        try {
            throw new Exception2();
        }
        catch (Exception2 e) {x += 3;}
        catch (Exception1 e) {x += 2;}
        catch (Exception e) {x += 1;}
    }
}


class Exception1 extends Exception {

}

class Exception2 extends Exception1 {

}
```